# Remove duplicates in dissimilaritie values measurement on R

Tags: r, duplicates

I try to remove duplicate in my dissimilaritie values from my beta diversity measures between plots, on R.

I have use `beta.pair.abund`function from *betapart* package to calculate the beta diversities between my plots,
and I obtain a data frame like that (it's only an overview):

```
     X    112101      115301      115701    135901    195902   
112101 0.0000000 0.931525424 0.997435897 0.5991379 0.5348837 
115301 0.9315254 0.000000000 0.007692308 0.8135776 0.5025278
115701 0.9974359 0.007692308 0.000000000 1.0000000 0.2666667
135901 0.5991379 0.813577586 1.000000000 0.0000000 0.4816810 
195902 0.5348837 0.502527806 0.266666667 0.4816810 0.0000000
```

The row and col names are my plots, and values the beta diversity.

My problem is that I don't know how I can remove the duplicate, to obtain something like that:

```
     X    112101      115301      115701    135901    195902   
112101 0.0000000        
115301 0.9315254 0.000000000 
115701 0.9974359 0.007692308 0.000000000 
135901 0.5991379 0.813577586 1.000000000 0.0000000  
195902 0.5348837 0.502527806 0.266666667 0.4816810 0.0000000
```

I'm interested if you have any ideas.Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the upper.tri function. For example:

```
my_data[upper.tri(my_data)]= NA
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is `lower.tri()`